# How should I do to transform a RDD[String] to RDD[(String, String)]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I got a `RDD[String]` from a file:

```
val file = sc.textFile("/path/to/myData.txt")
```

myData's format:

```
>str1_name
ATCGGKFKKVKKFKRLFFVLFLRL
FDJKALGFJVKRIKFKVKFGKLRL
...
FJDLALLLGL //the last line of str1
>str2_name
ATCGGKFKKVKKFKRLFFVLFLRL
FDJKALGFJVKRIKFKVKFGKLRL
...
FJDLALLLGL //the last line of str2
>str3_name
...
```

How should I do to transform the data from file to a structure `RDD[(String, String)]` ?
For instance,

```
trancRDD(
(str1_name, ATCGGKFKKVKKFKRLFFVLFLRLFDJKALGFJVKRIKFKVKFGKLRL), 
(str2_name, ATCGGKFKKVKKFKRLFFVLFLRLFDJKALGFJVKRIKFKVKFGKLRL),
...
)
```

Comment: We have done something similar using a custom hadoop input format, but it's non-trivial. If I were you, I'd rather write a small program to transform the input into a Spark-friendly format.

Comment: Because the transformation you want depends on elements "before" the current one (the previous line beginning with ">"), it's not really possible to distribute this across partitions (since the previous >-line might not be in the partition). So as @maasg says, some preprocessing to get the file into the right format would be better.

Comment: Found a way! See working sample below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a defined record separator, like ">" indicated above, this could be done using a custom Hadoop configuration:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

val conf = new Configuration
conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", ">")
// genome.txt contains the records provided in the question without the "..."
val dataset = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("./data/genome.txt", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)
val data = dataset.map(x=>x._2.toString)
```

Let's have a look at the data

```
data.collect
res11: Array[String] = 
Array("", "str1_name
ATCGGKFKKVKKFKRLFFVLFLRL
FDJKALGFJVKRIKFKVKFGKLRL
FJDLALLLGL 
", "str2_name
ATCGGKFKKVKKFKRLFFVLFLRL
FDJKALGFJVKRIKFKVKFGKLRL
FJDLALLLGL
")
```

We can easily make records out of this String

```
val records =  data.map{ multiLine => val lines = multiLine.split("\n"); (lines.head, lines.tail)}
records.collect
res14: Array[(String, Array[String])] = Array(("",Array()),
       (str1_name,Array(ATCGGKFKKVKKFKRLFFVLFLRL, FDJKALGFJVKRIKFKVKFGKLRL, FJDLALLLGL)),
       (str2_name,Array(ATCGGKFKKVKKFKRLFFVLFLRL, FDJKALGFJVKRIKFKVKFGKLRL, FJDLALLLGL)))
```

(use filter to take that first empty record out... exercise for the reader)